# Regex for roatating floating numbers

Tags: python, regex, nginx

i'm using the following regex `regex=re.compile("""(?P<responce_time>\s\d+\.\d+\s)""", re.M)`
to get all response times in my nginx log file

`line = 192.168.1.1 - - [08/Sep/2014:15:15:15 +0100]  "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 612 "-" "-" 4.038 - .`

The variable  line` is always rotating with new log entries

`print(Regex.match(line).groups())` 
this returns  *AttributeError: NoneType Object has no attribute group*

Any ideas ?

The regular expression is vaild http://regex101.com/r/yP5jV0/2,

Answer (score 2):

use `regex.search` instead of `regex.match`.  The [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the beginning of a string whereas [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) will match anywhere in the string.